# ccache basedir doesn't work as expected

Tags: ccache

I'm trying to make ccache work with the same source code built from different sibling directories. I've successfully set `CCACHE_BASEDIR` to the parent dir of these two siblings. If I do a build in `bld1` and then switch to `bld2` and build that copy (again, these are the same sources), I get no cache hits.

I'm now looking at the log output from setting `CCACHE_LOGFILE`. Unfortunately the log doesn't tell me what factors/data went into computing the hashes it looks up, I just see lots of "No such manifest file" message (for direct lookup, it seems).

Are there any other options I can use to debug the issue with ccache to figure out why it doesn't recognize these two source trees as identical?

Just to be clear, if I repeat the build in a given directory, I do indeed get lots of hits in the cache - so clearly ccache is working with an unchanging build path, it just doesn't seem to be working properly across directories.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is most likely to set `hash_dir = false` (`CCACHE_NOHASHDIR=1` if using environment variables) or setting `-fdebug-prefix-map=old=new` for relocating debug info to a common prefix (e.g. `-fdebug-prefix-map=$PWD=.`). More details can be found in the ["Compiling in different directories" section in the ccache manual](https://ccache.dev/manual/3.4.1.html#_compiling_in_different_directories).